# C++ "Building a series to solve a function" Why is my approximation off?

Tags: c++, c, function, built-in

So my question refers to my output mainly. I'm off of the "true" value of atan(x), whatever that may be. I know this has to be simple, what am I doing incorrect?

> Please enter the number you would like to apply arctan to as tan^(-1)*(x)
> remember, x cannot be greater than 1 or less than negative 1:.5
>
> The approx arctan of 0.5000 is 0.4794
> The true value arctan of 0.5000 is 0.4636
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double sum = 0.0, x, denom, term, z;
        int n, sign = -1;
        char again;
    
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter the number you would like to apply arctan to"
                << " as tan^(-1)*(x) \nremember, x cannot be greater than 1 or less than negative 1:";
            cin >> x;
            cout << endl;
            while (x > 1 || x < -1)
                {
                    cout << "Try again, the domain for arctan is ( -1 < x < 1): ";
                    cin >> x;
                    cout << endl;
                }
    
            if (x > -1 && x < 1)
                {   
                    for (n = 0; n < 19; n++)
                        {
                            sign = sign * (-1);
                            z = (n * 2) + 1;
                            if (n == 0)
                                denom = 1.0;
                            else
                                denom = denom*(2*n)*(2*n+1);
                            term = sign*pow(x, z)/denom;
                            sum = sum + term;
                        }
                }
    
            cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << "The approx arctan of " << x << " is " << sum << endl;
            cout << "The true value arctan of " << x << " is " << atan(x) << endl << endl;
    
            cout<<"Press Enter";
            cin.get();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << endl;
    
            cout << "Would you like to continue (Y/N)?";
            cin >> again;
            cout << endl;
        }
        while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It was about to test your program to see if I could replicate your problem. Fortunately I noticed that `system("PAUSE");` before I ran it. The `PAUSE` command on my computer pauses the cooling system for my nuclear reactor. You almost caused a meltdown with your [gratuitously non-portable code](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).

Comment: I think your `if` statement might be redundant, since you've already checked that `-1>x>1`.  Also, if `x` is exactly `-1` or `1` the `if` statement will be false and get skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your taylor expansion code is wrong.

Replace `denom = denom*(2*n)*(2*n+1);` with `denom = 2*n+1;` and it works

Comment: The expansion was explained to me as denom(old denom)*(2*n)*(2*n+1), could you advise me on why this is incorrect?

Comment: http://www.mathstat.concordia.ca/faculty/rhall/mc/arctan.pdf

Comment: also at wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series